# Managing builds with http cache revisions

Tags: git, caching

I have recently started working on front end development. The team I am working with right now, they run a grunt build task locally that adds version number to all assets and rewrite the paths in html and javascript files. Then they push this build to server. So dist directory and node_modules are also being tracked.
Problem I am facing is that every time I pull, I get conflicts due to change in asset names. Also the build is taking more than ten minutes, that also I have to check if that is normal.
 I want to know the best way to manage it so that I don't have to resolve conflicts on every pull. Possible solutions that are in my mind are-

1. Do not build locally but build on server only and use git version as suffix and not timestamp so that resource name is same across all servers. But the problem is that now all the servers will doing same thing and the final output will be same. So this seems to be waste of resource.
2. When ready to go into production cut a release branch, go to test server, build there and test. When ready to go into master, merge everything with master (also is it ok for master to contain only builds) and merge only source code back to develop branch.

Am I missing something in this ? Is there any better strategy ?